# what is the 'narrative'error here in the code?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE TABLE  CONSUMER_COMPLAINTS 
   (    
      DATE_RECEIVED STRING,
      PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR2(50), 
      SUB_PRODUCT VARCHAR2(40), 
      ISSUE VARCHAR2(100), 
      SUB_ISSUE VARCHAR2(100),
      CONSUMER COMPLAINT NARRATIVE VARCHAR2(100),
      Company Public Response STRING,
      Company VARCHAR(30),
      State Name CHAR(4),
      Zip_Code INTEGER,
      Tags VARCHAR(10),
      Consumer Consent Provided CHAR(6),
       Submitted via STRING,
      Date Sent_to_Company STRING,
     Company Response_to_Consumer VARCHAR(2),
     Timely Response CHAR(4),
     CONSUMER DISPUTED CHAR(4),
     COMPLAINT_ID NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

i tried to create a table but it is showing this error:
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 8 at position 25 unexpected 'NARRATIVE'. syntax error line 8 at position 35 unexpected 'VARCHAR2'. syntax error line 8 at position 43 unexpected '('.

Comment: Your column names should not have spaces I bet.

Answer (score 1):

Column names should not have spaces. The error is indicating the word `NARRATIVE` in your 8th line of code `CONSUMER COMPLAINT NARRATIVE VARCHAR2(100)` .

Please try below query:

```
CREATE TABLE CONSUMER_COMPLAINTS
(
    DATE_RECEIVED STRING,
    PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR(50),
    SUB_PRODUCT VARCHAR(40),
    ISSUE VARCHAR(100),
    SUB_ISSUE VARCHAR(100),
    CONSUMER_COMPLAINT_NARRATIVE VARCHAR(100),
    Company_Public_Response STRING,
    Company VARCHAR(30),
    State_Name CHAR(4),
    Zip_Code INTEGER,
    Tags VARCHAR(10),
    Consumer_Consent_Provided CHAR(6),
    Submitted_via STRING,
    Date_Sent_to_Company STRING,
    Company_Response_to_Consumer VARCHAR(2),
    Timely_Response CHAR(4),
    CONSUMER_DISPUTED CHAR(4),
    COMPLAINT_ID NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Comment: Or if you require spaces in the column name, you need to enclose the name in "". Example: "CONSUMER COMPLAINT NARRATIVE". Also, you should specify VARCHAR, not VARCHAR2 for Snowflake.